# How to lock the position of close button with paper component of modal in material ui for responsive screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I had built a cards page where I'm rendering multiple cards on a page. On clicking each card a popup card renders aka modal component but my close button is not responsive to the card.

Here is an image. See the button is going the wrong position when I open it to inspect.
[image]

Here is my [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-forest-7e6fw?file=/src/components/ImagePopup.js) to complete code at codesandbox.

**imagePopup.js modal component with close button**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import Backdrop from "@material-ui/core/Backdrop";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";
import { CloseOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5]
  },
  actionBtn: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 555,
    top: 85
  }
}));

export default function ImagePopup(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { openModal, setOpenModal, handleOpen, handleClose, img } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={openModal}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={openModal}>
          <div>
            <div className={classes.actionBtn}>
              <ActionButton
                // to edit icon functionality
                color="secondary"
                onClick={handleClose}
              >
                <CloseOutlined fontSize="small" />
              </ActionButton>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.paper}>
              <img src={img} height="500" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your `actionBtn` bloc style like this:

```js
actionBtn: {
    position: "absolute",
    marginLeft: 352,
    marginTop: -5,
    borderRadius: 0,
    '& > button': {
      background: "transparent" // If you want button to be transparent
    }
 }
```